# Python/Pandas: checking if values are fixed in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this table:

| index | index_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 6 |

I'm looking for an easy solution to detect if the values in the column 'index_1' are fixed or not. The best solution for my task would be if I get an additional column that looks like this one:

| index | index_1 | change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 5 | 0 |
| 9 | 6 | 0 |

I look forward to your reply and thank you in advance!

Comment: What does it mean that *values are fixed*?

Comment: Post an example script that includes an _initialized_ dataframe. By "fixed", does that mean that values will change? If so, have your test script demonstrate a change.

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: So I hope my example is now a bit clearer. The goal should be to detect whether a value occurs more than once and if so it should mark the values. For example value two in 'index_1' appears three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df['change'] = df.groupby('index_1').transform(lambda x: x.size > 1).astype(int)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   index  index_1  change
0      0        0       0
1      1        1       0
2      2        2       1
3      3        2       1
4      4        2       1
5      5        3       0
```

Complete example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 'index_1': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 5, 9: 6}})
df['change'] = df.groupby('index_1').transform(lambda x: x.size > 1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I get the following error message: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Comment: I've added a complete example for you.

Comment: The error message implies there are additional columns as transform without a column specified will perform the operation for all columns. Easy fix would be to specify the column. -> `df['change'] = df.groupby('index_1')['index_1'].transform(lambda x: x.size > 1).astype(int)`  Or capture all column transformations -> `df[['change1', 'chage2', 'change3','change4']] = df.groupby('index_1').transform(lambda x: x.size > 1).astype(int)` (assuming there are 4 items as the error indicates.)